# Usestate hook is not working inside onChange Handler

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to send my image data as base64url encoded form to the backend. I am able to get the base64 URL encoded value in my frontend but as I try to set it to something using useState hooks, I am facing issues. The value is not being set. My code is-

```
const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]

    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      console.log('reader result is-') 
      console.log(reader.result)
      setPreviewSource(reader.result)
      console.log('preview source value is-')
      console.log(previewSource)
    }
    try {
      console.log('reader result is-')
      console.log(reader.result)
      const imagedata = JSON.stringify(reader.result)

      await fetch('/api/uploads', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          data: previewSource,
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      setUploading(false)
    }
  }
```

As I consoled some values, I am getting values of `console.log(reader.result)` but If I set it to `setPreviewSource(reader.result)` it displays nothing but I am able to get the previewSource value inside my return .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx8gG.png)

> So, how can I get value inside previewSource so that I can send it to
> backend

.

Comment: Where do you call useState?

Comment: You can't change a state an expect the state to be changed in the same block of code. You'd have to wait till the next render cycle. React updates state asynchronously and by batches. That's why when you `console.log(previewSource)`, it will return the previous state (or your initial state if it's the first time the component is mounting). Also, in your `fetch`, I would use `data: reader.result` instead of `data: previewSource` due to this behavior.

Comment: You can't change a state an expect the state to be changed in the same block of code. You'd have to wait till the next render cycle. React updates state asynchronously and by batches. That's why when you `console.log(previewSource)`, it will return the previous state (or your initial state if it's the first time the component is mounting). Also, in your `fetch`, I would use `data: reader.result` instead of `data: previewSource` due to this behavior.

Comment: @SinanYaman did not include it here in my code but I have used it otherwise it would have said undefined.

Comment: @UpendraDhamala I understand that you used it but in order to grasp the code, I need to see it